# Converting a python code for Mac to Windows

Tags: python, file-io, cross-platform

I am new to python and I have a question about a piece of python code that creates a cleaned up output file from a model output file. This code was written for a Mac user, but now I want to run it in Windows. But it gives an error message. Could you help me in converting this code so I can use it in Windows? Thanks.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  fileName = sys.argv[1]
else:
  print "selected_um_b.out" #insert file name here
  sys.exit()

f = open(fileName)
counter = 0

fw = open(fileName+".cleaned", 'w')

for line in f:
   line = line.strip()
   counter = counter + 1
   if counter <= 4:
      fw.write(line+"\n");
      continue
   values = line.split("\t")
   if (values[4].strip() == "-99" or values[5].strip() == "0"): continue
   fw.write("\t".join(values)+"\n")

f.close()
```

**Update**

The error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\trial_batch\clean_output.py", line 7, in  sys.exit()
>   SystemExit

Comment: In the future, _edit_ your question when including more information.

Comment: @TimPost: Thanks. I was not familiar with how to do it. Thanks very much.

Comment: No worries. This seems answerable now, but do pay attention to comments on a frequent basis while your question is open and then edit your question to address them :)

Comment: I'm just curious, where the heck did my comment go?

Comment: @NiklasR: I am sorry, I haven't deleted anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program expects a filename on the command line when you execute it. It appears you did not provide one, so the program exited (the `sys.exit()` call terminates the program).

How are you trying to use it?  If you just want to convert one file, put the file and the Python script into the same directory. Replace lines 3 through 7 with `filename = "yourfilename.typ"` (do not indent the line); it will read the file ("yourfilename.typ" in my example) and write an output file with 'cleaned' in the filename.

Comment: It's a bit strange, though. A call to sys.exit() raises a SystemExit exception, which halts the interpreter, but I don't think it should print a traceback in the normal case.

Comment: @Art Swri: Thanksvery much. I modified the code based on your suggestion and put the code and file into same directory. My file name is amd_ex3. Now the error message is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Bart\bart.py", line 17, in <module>
    f = open(amd_ex3.dat)
NameError: name 'amd_ex3' is not defined

Comment: You did not do what I suggested, but instead put the filename into the open() call. That's fine too - just put quotes around it; it's a string. (I am assuming you deleted the lines from `if len(sys.argv) > 1:` through `system.exit`.)

Comment: @ArtSwri: I am sorry. I may have made a mistake. Here is the code after modifying: import sys
#if len(sys.argv) > 1:
#    fileName = sys.argv[1]
##else:
#    print "data.out" #insert file name here
#    sys.exit()
filename = "amd_ex3.dat"
f = open(amd_ex3.dat)
    
counter = 0
fw = open(amd_ex3.dat+".cleaned", 'w')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter <= 4:
        fw.write(line+"\n");
        continue
    values = line.split("\t")
    if (values[4].strip() == "-99" or values[5].strip() == "0"): continue
    fw.write("\t".join(values)+"\n")
f.close()

Comment: @ArtSwri: Sorry, I got what you said. I put "" around all filenames ("amd_ex3.dat") and it worked. Now I get a new error message that says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Bart\bart.py", line 30, in <module>
    if (values[4].strip() == "-99" or values[5].strip() == "0"): continue
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The line `values = line.split("\t")` splits input lines (after the 4th line) into chunks that are separated by tabs. (That's what the backslash-t means - a tab). The parts are put into the 'values' variable, which will be an array (actually a list, but you can think of it as an array). The likely problem is that some line contains fewer than 6 chunks; the `values[4]` and `values[5]` pick the 5th and 6th chunks from the array. (Numbering starts with zero, note one). Check your input file format.

Comment: BTW the program is set up to skip lines whose 5th chunk is '-99' as well as ones with 6th chunk is '0'. (Don't mean to be second-guessing you, but this may be easier for you to do manually with an editor if this is a one-time thing...)

Comment: @ArtSwri: Thank you very much for your help. That is right. There was a problem in input file. But the code is working now. About how I am using the code: I am using to convert the output file of model so every time that I get output from my model, I use this script. Thanks again for your time. That was very helpful.